# Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3

Tags: python, parsing, configparser, python-config

I'm reading a config file in python getting sections and creating new config files for each section.

However.. I'm getting a decode error because one of the strings contains `Español=spain`

```
self.output_file.write( what.replace( " = ", "=", 1 ) )
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How would I adjust my code to allow for encoded characters such as these? I'm very new to this so please excuse me if this is something simple..

```
class EqualsSpaceRemover:
    output_file = None
    def __init__( self, new_output_file ):
        self.output_file = new_output_file

    def write( self, what ):
        self.output_file.write( what.replace( " = ", "=", 1 ) )

def get_sections():
    configFilePath = 'C:\\test.ini'
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.optionxform = str
    config.read(configFilePath)
    for section in config.sections():
        configdata = {k:v for k,v in config.items(section)}
        confignew = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        cfgfile = open("C:\\" + section + ".ini", 'w')
        confignew.add_section(section)
        for x in configdata.items():
            confignew.set(section,x[0],x[1])
        confignew.write( EqualsSpaceRemover( cfgfile ) )
        cfgfile.close()
```

Comment: check if `what.replace( " = ", "=", 1 ).encode('utf-8')` works

Comment: I just tested and it gave me the following: `self.output_file.write( what.replace( " = ", "=", 1 ).encode('utf-8') )
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Remove first line (+ create with utf-8)!

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid but what do you mean? this is the first time I've worked with encoding

Comment: what if you open the file with `utf-8`? like `import codecs;codecs.open("C:\\" + section + ".ini", 'w', encoding='utf-8'))`

Comment: This seems python2 to me. If so, please add the appropriate tag, as unicode handling is completely different between python2 and python3. Are you using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`? That would explain why you get an UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: @ mic4eal that still produced the same error.

@mata you are correct and by removing `from __future__ import unicode_literals` fixed the issue! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `python2` with `from __future__ import unicode_literals` then every string literal you write is an unicode literal, as if you would prefix every literal with `u"..."`, unless you explicitly write `b"..."`.

This explains why you get an Unicode*Decode*Error on this line:

```
what.replace(" = ", "=", 1)
```

because what you actually do is

```
what.replace(u" = ",u"=",1 )
```

`ConfigParser` uses plain old `str` for its items when it reads a file using the `parser.read()` method, which means `what` will be a `str`. If you use unicode as arguments to `str.replace()`, then the string is converted (decoded) to unicode, the replacement applied and the result returned as unicode. But if `what` contains characters that can't be decoded to unicode using the default encoding, then you get an UnicodeDecodeError where you wouldn't expect one.

So to make this work you can

- use explicit prefixes for byte strings: `what.replace(b" = ", b"=", 1)`
- or remove the `unicode_litreals` future import.

Generally you shouldn't mix `unicode` and `str` (python3 fixes this by making it an error in almost any case). You should be aware that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` changes every non prefixed literal to unicode and doesn't automatically change your code to work with unicode in all case. Quite the opposite in many cases.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the "right" way of solving the problem. This solution ignores that the character encoding of the text and hopes for the best. A better solution is to make sure the config files (both reading and writing) are opened with the correct character encoding (which appears to be utf-8 [according to OP's deleted answer]). By default, py2 uses the OS' default encoding (which appears to be something other than utf-8).

Comment: @Dunes - In python2 `ConfigParser` doesn't assume any encoding on a config file, it's read as binary file (at least when using the `read(path)` method), and the data is stored as bytes (`str`) internally and written back as bytes. You can use something like `parser.readfp(codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8'))`, then unicode will be used for everything, but like many other modules it's intended and documented to be used with `str`. In python3 it's a different story, there it only works with unicode.